# Exclude EurekaClient Bean from Application Context in SpringBootApplicationTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to write a integration test against my Spring Data API with the following test configuration.

```yml
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
[..] # No other configuration part that affects discovery/eureka client
```

This is my test class

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Transactional
class FooAPITest {
  
  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
  }

}
```

However I have a component which injects the EurekaClient to get a service instance from it

```java
@Component
public class ServiceClient {

  @Autowired
  public ServiceClient(@Qualifier("eurekaClient") EurekaClient eurekaClient) {
    URI serviceUri = URI.create(eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka("service", false).getHomePageUrl());
  }

}
```

So as of this service my application is not able to load the ApplicationContext.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="eurekaClient")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 81 more
```

**What I've tried so far**

I thought about setting up a custom ContextConfiguration to exclude the `ServiceClient` as it is not needed in the test class. However I need to include a Configuration File which autowires the EntityManager but when I use `@SpringBootApplication(classes = {Configuration.class})` the EntityManager can not be injected. This Configuration looks like that:

```java
@Configuration
class Configuration {
  @Autowired
  EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

This produces the same error but with EntityManager Bean:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 81 more
```

**Current Workaround**

Currently I'm avoiding the problem by mocking the `ServiceClient` but I want to get rid of that code smell.

```java
@MockBean
ServiceClient serviceClient;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(FooAPITest.class);
}
```

Another workaround would be to mark the Injected Beans as not required but I don't find that practicable only to make the tests work.

What is a proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try mocking the `EurekaClient` in your test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Transactional
class FooAPITest {
  
  @MockBean
  private EurekaClient eurekaClient;
  
  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
  }

}
```

This will create the `EurekaClient` as a mocked bean in the `ApplicationContext` to be injected into your service.

If you have other tests that initialize the Spring `ApplicationContext`, you can create a separate configuration class within the application package to be scanned (using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation to cover all bases):

```
@Configuration
public class MockEurekaConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean 
  public EurekaClient eurekaClient() {
    return Mockito.mock(EurekaClient.class);
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunally this is as mentioned in my question my workarount at the moment. But I don't find this a clean solution.

Comment: If I understand it correctly I'm forced to mock the client in every test which builds the application context. This leads to much redundant and uneccessary code and couples the test to Mockito. I don't like that workaround. However I think my code has some kind of design issue that could be solved in another way than mocking.

Comment: Well, you definitely need `EurekaClient` bean since you want it as required. So it either has to be the real bean or a mocked bean. I've made an edit to create the mocked `EurekaClient` for all spring tests.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a good compromise for now. Will mark as accepted answer when no other possible answer will convince me.

Comment: I made an edit. It should be the normal `@Configuration` annotation, not `@TestConfiguration`, FYI.

Comment: I was so brazen and edited your answer again. As the code is now, it works in my context.  It was necessary to stick to `@TestConfiguration` as `@Configuration` somehow overwrites or disables the productive Configuration classes.